# history doesn't save in zsh

Tags: linux, zsh, command-history

I'm using zsh and want the history tobehave like it does in bash. I have the following in my `~/.zshrc`:

```
export FZF_BASE=/usr/bin/fzf
export HISTFILE=$HOME/.histfile
export SAVEHIST=500
export HISTSIZE=500
plugins=(
...
fzf
)
```

but for some reason, there is no `~/.histfile` at all, why not? What else am I missing?

Comment: Apart from `FZF_BASE`, none of those variables need to be exported. This is not the issue though, but you may possibly find that the file is created _after exiting an interactive `zsh` session_. The history is only saved when the shell exits by default. I'm not turning this into a real answer since I don't know the circumstances under which you are testing this.

Comment: @Kusalananda you can change your comment into an answer. I actually rebooted the machine and afterwards, it worked as expected!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616620/history-doesnt-save-in-zsh?noredirect=1#comment1153453_616620), the `zsh` shell saves its command line history to the file referenced by the `HISTFILE` shell variable as soon as the shell terminates, but not before that by default.  You would therefore not expect to see the file spring into existence until the termination of an interactive shell with `HISTFILE` set.

There shell options that you may set with `setopt` to write the shell's history to file after each command, e.g. `INC_APPEND_HISTORY`, `INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME`, or `SHARE_HISTORY`, but you should probably read about these and associated history-related shell options in the `zshoptions` manual (`man zshoptions`, then search for e.g. `HIST`).

Note that the history related shell variables (mentioned in the `zshparam` manual) are not environment variables, and that they therefore should not be exported.

Answer (score -2):

When one changes `HISTFILE`, in `bash`, and probably `zsh`, one must restart the history by setting `HISTSIZE` to 0, then the desired value.

```
HISTSIZE=0
HISTSIZE=500
```